# How to send direct message with Twitter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oauth, twitter, mgtwitterengine

in my iphone application i have to send direct message throughout twitter,
the problem is that twitter had changed the authentication from basic authentication to oauth 
and tutorial on the Web are out of date

so i use SAOauthTwitterEngine for the authentication part and all ok. but these classes don't use the api, so i have to use MGTwitterEngine for this.

the problem is that MGTE dont have oauth but only xauth and basic authentication, and i cant use this together anyone know how to do it? or know a tutorial that explain it.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you OAuth because xAuth requires you to send an email to twitter askeing them to give you the permission, and you have to write a reort on your application (this isn't good for a testing app)
have you tried this?
https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Comment: yes i use oauth, and i haven't test this example i will try it soon

Comment: i have tried this but this implements only the authentication part , nothing about the apis

Answer (score 1):

in my app I am sending direct messages to my twitter followers by using MGTwitterEngine let have a look:

```
appDelegate._engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
appDelegate._engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
appDelegate._engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;
```

once you get authenticated this method get called

```
    #pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterControllerDelegate

    - (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *)username {
     NSLog(@"Authenicated for %@", username);
     [appDelegate._engine sendDirectMessage:@"Test for Twitter direct message" to:username];
}
```

Hope this will help you.